# Webcam found by lsusb but not by anything else

Tags: usb, video, webcam

I have two identical webcams (Microsoft LifeCam HD-3000) which I want to use with my linux box. For now, I have connected just one, but it's not found by cheese (or obs-studio).
So I ran

```
$ lsusb

Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub 
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 045e:0779 Microsoft Corp. LifeCam HD-3000 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 1a40:0101 Terminus Technology Inc. Hub 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0513:0318 digital-X, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

But that is all I get!

```
$ modprobe v4l2loopback
$ sudo dmesg | grep -i camera
```

Both output nothing.
And this just shows a dummy device:

```
$ sudo v4l2-ctl --list-devices
Dummy video device (0x0000) (platform:v4l2loopback-000):
        /dev/video0
```

It's quite a fresh installation, after an attempt to upgrade 20.04 to 22.04 that went terribly wrong. I deleted all partitions and installed 22.04 with whatever was needed to use graphics and video devices.

I must admit, that on the 20.04, while it was a struggle, it eventually worked and I was able to connect both cameras.

Any ideas about what am I doing wrong?

Thank you.

Comment: Note: I did find a couple of similar questions but in both cases the webcam was found by either modprobe or dmesg. This is not the case here.

Comment: According to [this](https://linux-hardware.org/index.php?id=usb:045e-0810) the device is supported by the `uvc_driver` in the kernel. Where did the `v4l2` stuff come from?

Comment: What do you mean?